# How to run multiple mongo db commands in bash script without using javascript?

Tags: mongodb, bash, shell, scripting

Command below works

```
mongo --host mymongoserver < myscript.js
```

But I don't want to split my logic between 2 files :|

Comment: Does it work if you just concatenate the two files, e.g. `cat myscript.js myotherscript.js | mongo --host mymongoserver` ?

Comment: @thatotherguy i meant a js file and and .sh file